# Excel 2013 auto formatting delimeters

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I wanted to know how to convert delimeted values in a column to a certain format. Example, if i had the following values in one cell/column "Black;Dark Blue;Light Blue" and would want to convert it to look like this "Black:0:0:0:1|Dark Blue:0:0:0:2|Light Blue:0:0:0:3" what is the best way to achieve this result?

Comment: I'm sure some wizard could craft an ugly excel formula to do this but I think that VBA is best suited for such complicated functions. This is not generally a site where people just write code for you but I suppose someone might. If someone gave you VBA code do you know how to run and troubleshoot it?

Comment: @HackSlash *generally* is an understatement. SuperUser is **not** a free scripting service. If you want us to help you, you should show what you have tried, and where it failed, *then* we can help you point out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My time is worthless.

```
Sub delimitAddNum()
    'e.g. input: Black;Dark Blue;Light Blue
    'e.g. output: Black:0:0:0:1|Dark Blue:0:0:0:2|Light Blue:0:0:0:3
    theStr = ActiveCell.Value

    If InStr(theStr, ";") = False Then Exit Sub

    theSplit = Split(theStr, ";")

    theResult = ""

    For i = 0 To UBound(theSplit)
        If i < UBound(theSplit) Then
            theResult = theResult & theSplit(i) & ":0:0:0:" & (i + 1) & "|"
        Else
            theResult = theResult & theSplit(i) & ":0:0:0:" & i + 1
        End If
    Next i

    theChk = MsgBox("Do you want to overwrite cell " & Replace(ActiveCell.Address, "$", "") & _
    " with the following result?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    theResult, vbYesNo, "Delimiter, Number Thingy")

    If theChk = vbYes Then ActiveCell.Value = theResult
End Sub
```